# User email not showing in template [METEOR]!

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have a user index and would like to display information on each user. User ID shows up fine, but the app isn't showing emails.

Here is my template:

```
<template name="users">
  <h1>List of all users</h1>
  {{#each users}}
    <div class="list_item">
      <p>ID: {{_id}}</p>
      <p>Email: {{email}}</p>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

And here are my routes:

```
Router.route('/users', function () {
  this.render('users');
}, {
  waitOn: function() {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('users')
    ]
  },

  data:  {users: Meteor.users.find({})}
});
```

And finally, my publication:

```
Meteor.publish('users', function () {
  return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {emails: 1, profile: 1}});
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: First, it's emails, not email, and it won't show anything because address is nested in email field and is also an array, check it in mongo because I'm on my phone now

Comment: Just an observation... Publishing the emails property will make all email addresses available to all users, through the debug console, even if you don't display it in the UI.

Comment: Hi Brian, thank you for the tip. I am currently just playing around with Meteor, and this isn't going to be published as a site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to display the email would be :

```
<p>Email: {{emails.[0].address}}</p>
```

Email addresses are stored as an array in the user object.

You can check by typing `Meteor.user()` in the console :

```
Object {
  ...
  emails: Array[1]
    0: Object{
      address: "username@domain.com",
      verified: false
    }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ah that was it! I was using emails[0].address before

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ currentUser.emails.[0].address }}
```